# import library doesn't work

Tags: java, import

What I want to do is simple, I just want to use `@JsonIgnore` to omit some fields in the json response. So I added `@JsonIgnore` in the member variable level like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
private int instanceId;
```

But this only works when I import `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`, but I want to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`. And this annotation doesn't work with the later library.

How should I resolve this? 
(the reason I want to use `fasterxml.jackson` is because I want to use `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)` for some other fields)

Comment: Are you saying that you want to use two incompatible versions of the same library at the same time in the same code?

Comment: no, I only want to use one library which is `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore`

Comment: `JsonIgnore` isn't a library, it's an annotation from a library. What is the "later library" to which you alluded, and what is the "earlier library"?